# Why threads implemented in kernel space are slow?

Tags: multithreading, performance, operating-system, kernel

> When a thread does something that may cause it to become blocked locally, for example, waiting for another thread in its process to complete some work, it calls a run-time system procedure. This procedure checks to see if the thread must be put into blocked state. If so, it stores the thread's registers in the thread table, looks in the table for a ready thread to run, and reloads the machine registers with the new thread's saved values. As soon as the stack pointer and program counter have been switched, the new thread comes to life again automatically. If the machine happens to have an instruction to store all the registers and another one to load them all, the entire thread switch can be done in just a handful of instructions. Doing thread switching like this is at least an order of magnitude-maybe more-faster than trapping to the kernel and is a strong argument in favor of user-level threads packages.

Source: Modern Operating Systems (Andrew S. Tanenbaum | Herbert Bos)

The above argument is made in favor of user-level threads. The user-level thread implementation is depicted as kernel managing all the processes, where individual processes can have their own run-time (made available by a library package) that manages all the threads in that process.

Of course, merely calling a function in the run-time than trapping to kernel might have a few less instructions to execute but why the difference is so huge?

For example, if threads are implemented in kernel space, every time a thread has to be created the program is required to make a system call. Yes. But the call only involves adding an entry to the thread table with certain attributes (which is also the case in user space threads). When a thread switch has to happen, kernel can simply do what the run-time (at user-space) would do. The only real difference I can see here is that the kernel is being involved in all this. How can the performance difference be so significant?

Comment: "Threads implemented as a library package in user space perform significantly better" Please give a source for this affirmation. Also, I don't see how threads can be implemented purly in a library without kernel support, unless you are talking about green threads, in which case you are comparing oranges with apples. Please clarify what you mean and where do you get your comparison results.

Comment: @bolov Source is the book I am reading: Modern Operating Systems 4th ed by Andrew S. Tanenbaum and Herbert Bos. It says, threads implemented as a part of runtime in user-space  are order of a magnitude  (or more) faster than threads implemented in kernel.

Comment: I don't have the book at hand and it's been a while since I've read it, but I bet there is more context than that. Yes, there are situations when green threads (if that's what we are actually talking about) perform better than native threads, but you can't generalize and say an absolute affirmation like that, and I believe the book doesn't do that either.

Comment: @bolov Added a paragraph from that book to explain the context, if that helps.

Comment: If anything is to be described as faster/slower, it would be thread context changes, not 'threads'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Threads implemented as a library package in user space perform significantly better. Why?

They're not.

The fact is that most task switches are caused by threads blocking (having to wait for IO from disk or network, or from user, or for time to pass, or for some kind of semaphore/mutex shared with a different process, or some kind of pipe/message/packet from a different process) or caused by threads unblocking (because whatever they were waiting for happened); and most reasons to block and unblock involve the kernel in some way (e.g. device drivers, networking stack, ...); so doing task switches in kernel when you're already in the kernel is faster (because it avoids the overhead of switching to user-space and back for no sane reason).

Where user-space task switching "works" is when kernel isn't involved at all. This mostly only happens when someone failed to do threads properly (e.g. they've got thousands of threads and coarse-grained locking and are constantly switching between threads due to lock contention, instead of something sensible like a "worker thread pool"). It also only works when all threads are the same priority - you don't want a situation where very important threads belonging to one process don't get CPU time because very unimportant threads belonging to a different process are hogging the CPU (but that's exactly what happens with user-space threading because one process has no idea about threads belonging to a different process).

Mostly; user-space threading is a silly broken mess. It's not faster or "significantly better"; it's worse.

> When a thread does something that may cause it to become blocked locally, for example, waiting for another thread in its process to complete some work, it calls a run-time system procedure. This procedure checks to see if the thread must be put into blocked state. If so, it stores the thread's registers in the thread table, looks in the table for a ready thread to run, and reloads the machine registers with the new thread's saved values. As soon as the stack pointer and program counter have been switched, the new thread comes to life again automatically. If the machine happens to have an instruction to store all the registers and another one to load them all, the entire thread switch can be done in just a handful of instructions. Doing thread switching like this is at least an order of magnitude-maybe more-faster than trapping to the kernel and is a strong argument in favor of user-level threads packages.

This is talking about a situation where the CPU itself does the actual task switch (and either the kernel or a user-space library tells the CPU when to do a task switch to what). This has some relatively interesting history behind it...

In the 1980s Intel designed a CPU ("iAPX" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432 ) for "secure object oriented programming"; where each object has its own isolated memory segments and its own privilege level, and can transfer control directly to other objects. The general idea being that you'd have a single-tasking system consisting of global objects using cooperating flow control. This failed for multiple reasons, partly because all the protection checks ruined performance, and partly because the majority of software at the time was designed for "multi-process preemptive time sharing, with procedural programming".

When Intel designed protected mode (80286, 80386) they still had hopes for "single-tasking system consisting of global objects using cooperating flow control". They included hardware task/object switching, local descriptor table (so each task/object can have its own isolated segments), call gates (so tasks/objects can transfer control to each other directly), and modified a few control flow instructions (`call far` and `jmp far`) to support the new control flow. Of course this failed for the same reason iAPX failed; and (as far as I know) nobody has ever used these things for the "global objects using cooperative flow control" they were originally designed for. Some people (e.g. very early Linux) did try to use the hardware task switching for more traditional "multi-process preemptive time sharing, with procedural programming" systems; but found that it was slow because the hardware task switch did too many protection checks that could be avoided by software task switching and saved/reloaded too much state that could be avoided by a software task switching;p and didn't do any of the other stuff needed for a task switch (e.g. keeping statistics of CPU time used, saving/restoring debug registers, etc).

Now.. Andrew S. Tanenbaum is a micro-kernel advocate. His ideal system consists of isolated pieces in user-space (processes, services, drivers, ...) communicating via. synchronous messaging. In practice (ignoring superficial differences in terminology) this "isolated pieces in user-space communicating via. synchronous messaging" is almost entirely identical to Intel's twice failed "global objects using cooperative flow control".

Mostly; in theory (if you ignore all the practical problems, like CPU not saving all of the state, and wanting to do extra work on task switches like tracking statistics), for a specific type of OS that Andrew S. Tanenbaum prefers (micro-kernel with synchronous message passing, without any thread priorities), it's plausible that the paragraph quoted above is more than just wishful thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this can use a lot of OS and parallel distributive computing knowledge (And I am not sure about the answer but I will try my best)

So if you think about it. The library package will have a greater amount of performance than you write in the kernel itself. In the package thing, interrupt given by this code will be held at once and al the execution will be done. While when you write in kernel different other interrupts can come before. Plus accessing threads again and again is harsh on the kernel since everytime there will be an interrupt. I hope it will be a better view.

Answer (score 0):

it's not correct to say the user-space threads are better that the kernel-space threads since each one has its own pros and cons.
in terms of user-space threads, as the application is responsible for managing thread, its easier to implement such threads and that kind of threads have not much reliance on OS. however, you are not able to use the advantages of multi processing.
In contrary, the kernel space modules are handled by OS, so you need to implement them according to the OS that you use, and it would be a more complicated task. However, you have more control over your threads.
for more comprehensive tutorial, take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_multi_threading.htm).

Comment: I didn't say anything about any of the approach being better or worse. The concern here is only performance.

Comment: @DevashishJaiswal performance is measured by varieties of factors.